# Обфускация личных данных в MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, резервное-копирование, gdpr

Подскажите как решить задачку с обезличиванием личных данных клиентов в базе MySQL. Моя задача состоит в том что бы при бекапе были обезличены личные данные клиентов - ФИО, емаил. Есть e-commerce CMS, и я хочу что бы при бекапе эти данные были изменены. Как это реализовать? Есть ли примеры? Я себе представляю это как изменения данных во время бекапа на лету. Другой вариант это копия базы и изменение данных через sql запросы, и потом обезличеный бекап. Подскажите как сделать правильно и если можно пример.

Comment: Хм. Какой же это бекап если из него нельзя восстановить базу?

Comment: моя задача в том что бы иметь 2 бекапа. один полный (для клиента) и один обезличеный (для девелоперов)

Comment: Ну не выгружайте эти поля, делов-то... или заливайте их рандомным фэйком. *Моя задача состоит в том что бы при бекапе* Как ВЫ намерены делать бэкап - нам предложено догадаться, надо понимать?

Comment: Например, ФИО может быть заменено на любой чексумм от него, а мыло - то же, но с добавкой *@host.fake*. Делается, например, изготовлением вьюшки и бэкапом её данных вместо данных таблицы.

Comment: бекап хочу делать через mysqldump. как их на лету менять? нужен какой то скрипт?

Comment: *бекап хочу делать через mysqldump* Не лечится. mysqldump дампит данные "как есть" - т.е. в этом случае нужно обфуськать данные, сделать бэкап, потом ревертнуться. Я бы на такое не решился, тем более на боевой системе. Бэкапьте отдельно структуру  и данные таблиц, которые не требуют маскирования (едино для всех), а данные таблиц с персоналкой выгружайте отдельными SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE (для девелопов - с фуськами) и загружайте через LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: спасибо посмотрю.

Comment: А я бы пускал весь вывод mysqldump не в файл, а на вход скрипту, на любом языке, позволяющем легко манипулировать текстом. Этот скрипт конечно должен знать структуру БД, что бы знать что менять. Распарсить поток SQL-команд insert, которые генерит mysqldump достаточно простая задача. Таким образом меняем на лету содержимое дампа и в файл уже пишем измененное. Как вариант, если делаются два дампа, делаем полный дамп, а скриптом обрабатываем получившийся файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил задачу с GDPR данными обычной маскировкой данных функциями MySQL.

```
mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% %GDPR_DB_NAME% -e "DROP DATABASE %GDPR_DB_NAME%"

mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% -e "CREATE DATABASE %GDPR_DB_NAME%"

mysqldump -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% %DB_NAME% | mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% %GDPR_DB_NAME%

mysql -u %DB_LOGIN% -p%DB_PASSWORD% -D %GDPR_DB_NAME% -e "UPDATE "customer_address_entity" SET company = CONCAT(SUBSTR(company, 1, 6), REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(company) - 6));" -vvv
```

Answer (score 2):

Бекап БД подразумевает сохранение данных, а задача в изменении данных. Если для разработчиков не нужно чтобы количество записей в таблицах было одинаковым в основной базе и дев базе, а нужна именно структура. Можно подготовить тестовые данные для дев базы один раз. Изменив либо часть основной базы, либо всю если нужны все записи. А далее изменяете только структуру, если она менялась, миграциями обычно.
Если все таки нужны для чего то все данные бекапа, но измененные. То стоит написать миграцию (набор sql запросов изменяющих данные) и применять ее к свежему бекапу, в потом отдавать дамп разработчикам. Для автоматизации или bash или консольное приложение, смотря что у вас там конкретно стоит и как удобнее.
Хорошая практика это иметь базу с тестовыми данными и менять только структуру, если она поменялась через миграции.